# finding spots and lines in image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I was working on following images to find lines and spots in these images. I am working with *OpenCV*, **C++**. I have tried *HoughLineP*, *HoughLine*, *Contour* and *Canny* methods but couldn't get the results. If someone can help or write a pseudo-code, I shall be grateful.

Thanks.

**Image to detect line:**
[image: Image to detect line]

**Image to detect spot:**
[image: Image to detect spot]

Comment: Please share the code you tried to get this working. Do you expect us to deliver you a canned solution ?

Comment: it is hard even for my eyes to detect lines.. just curious to know from you get this messy images?

Comment: Where did you get these images from? Is it some sort of cosmic data? It would be interesting..

Comment: you can find them here https://babelia.libraryofbabel.info/slideshow.html share any solution if you found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmmm - where did you get those awful images? Well, they were worth 2 minutes of effort... the spot is lighter than the rest, so if you divide the image into 100 rectangles and find the brightest ones, you will probably get it... I use ImageMagick here just at the command line - it is installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows:

```
convert noise.jpg -crop 10x10@ -format "%[mean] %g\n" info: | sort -n

32123.3 640x416+384+291
32394.6 640x416+256+42
32442.2 640x416+320+125
32449.1 640x416+384+250
32459.6 640x416+192+374
32464.4 640x416+0+374
32486.5 640x416+448+125
32491.4 640x416+576+374
32493.7 640x416+576+333
32504.3 640x416+576+83
32520.9 640x416+576+0
32527 640x416+448+0
32621.8 640x416+384+333
32624.1 640x416+320+42
32631.3 640x416+192+333
32637.8 640x416+384+42
32643.4 640x416+512+0
32644.2 640x416+0+0
32652.6 640x416+384+83
32659.1 640x416+128+374
32660.4 640x416+320+208
32662.2 640x416+384+0
32668.5 640x416+256+208
32669.4 640x416+0+333
32676.7 640x416+256+250
32683.5 640x416+256+83
32699.7 640x416+0+208
32701.3 640x416+64+166
32704 640x416+576+208
32704 640x416+64+333
32707.5 640x416+512+208
32710.8 640x416+192+83
32729.8 640x416+320+83
32733.4 640x416+256+166
32735 640x416+576+250
32741 640x416+256+125
32745.4 640x416+0+166
32748.4 640x416+320+166
32751.4 640x416+512+166
32752.4 640x416+512+42
32755.1 640x416+384+208
32770.9 640x416+448+291
32776.8 640x416+128+166
32777.1 640x416+256+0
32795.8 640x416+512+125
32801.5 640x416+128+333
32803.3 640x416+192+125
32805.5 640x416+256+374
32809.6 640x416+448+166
32810 640x416+576+166
32822.2 640x416+0+291
32822.8 640x416+576+42
32826.8 640x416+320+333
32831.7 640x416+320+0
32834.8 640x416+192+42
32837.6 640x416+192+166
32843 640x416+384+125
32862 640x416+64+374
32865.8 640x416+0+42
32871.5 640x416+576+291
32872.5 640x416+0+83
32872.8 640x416+448+333
32873.6 640x416+320+291
32877.5 640x416+448+42
32880.5 640x416+64+208
32883.5 640x416+128+42
32883.9 640x416+192+208
32885.5 640x416+128+208
32889.2 640x416+256+333
32921 640x416+192+291
32923.3 640x416+64+291
32929.2 640x416+512+374
32935.4 640x416+192+250
32938.4 640x416+64+250
32943.5 640x416+448+374
32953.3 640x416+384+374
32954.7 640x416+320+374
32962 640x416+320+250
32966.9 640x416+448+83
32967.3 640x416+128+291
32968.3 640x416+0+250
32970.8 640x416+512+333
32974.5 640x416+64+0
32979.6 640x416+512+291
32983.6 640x416+256+291
32988.9 640x416+448+250
32993.3 640x416+576+125
33012.7 640x416+0+125
33057.3 640x416+512+250
33068.6 640x416+128+250
33102.9 640x416+64+42
33126.1 640x416+512+83
33127.9 640x416+384+166
33139.2 640x416+192+0
33141.4 640x416+64+83
33142.3 640x416+64+125
33181.5 640x416+448+208
33190.8 640x416+128+0
34693 640x416+128+125
36178.3 640x416+128+83
```

The last 2 rectangles are the brightest, so if I box them in in red and blue you can see what it has found:

```
convert noise.jpg -fill none -stroke red -draw "rectangle 128,83 192,123" -stroke blue -draw "rectangle 128,125 192,168" result.png
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could create a new image in which each pixel is the mean of the 50x50 square of surrounding pixels in the original image, like this:

```
convert noise.jpg -virtual-pixel edge -statistic mean 50x50 -auto-level result.png
```

[image]

Of course, you can also threshold that:

```
convert noise.jpg -virtual-pixel edge -statistic mean 50x50 -auto-level -threshold 80% result.png
```

[image]

As regards the lines, I want to use some type of `mode` to detect the frequently occurring values within small areas but as the colours vary, I need to reduce the palette of colours to find things that are just *similarly coloured* so I would go with an approach something like this which reduces the colours then calculates the mode:

```
convert noise2.jpg -colors 8 -statistic mode 8x8 result.jpg
```

[image]

It needs refinement, but you get the idea hopefully.

Alternatively, you could calculate a new image wherein each pixel is the standard deviation of the surrounding 3x3 pixels in the original image and then look for the ones where this value is lowest - i.e. where the image is darkest which corresponds to areas in the input image where there is least variation in the pixel colours:

```
convert noise2.png -statistic standarddeviation  3x3 -auto-level result.png
```

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me which visual studio version you use with ImageMagick. Can i compile binary for visual studio 2015?

Comment: I just run those commands at the command prompt (Terminal window) - I didn't compile anything - I downloaded the ImageMagick executables. You can download and use ImageMagick with Visual Studio, but there is no need, you can do just the same processing in OpenCV anyway.